# What does the following mean with respect to enumerations in C programming?

Tags: c, types, enums

In a book I'm reading, enumeration constants have been introduced before arrays. Use of arrays has been demonstrated only through a couple examples. Following is stated :

```
enum corvid { magpie, raven, jay, corvid_num};

char const * const bird [ corvid_num ] = 
{
  [raven] = "raven",
  [magpie] = "magpie",
  [jay] = "jay",
};

for ( unsigned i = 0; i < corvid_num ; ++i)
  printf ("Corvid %u is the %s\n", i, bird[i]);
```

> This declares a new integer type enum corvid for which we know four different values.

> Takeaway - Enumeration constants have either an explicit or a positional value

> As you might have guessed, positional values start from 0 onward, so in our example
> we have raven with value 0, magpie with 1, jay with 2, and corvid_num with 3. This last
> 3 is obviously the 3 we are interested in.

Question 1:

Does `[magpie] = "magpie"` imply that `magpie`th position refers to value `"magpie"`.

Question 2:

According to loop, how is `bird[0]` equal to `"raven"` , since this is explicit and not a positional value. Also after the first iteration is `[i + 1]` gonna be equal to `[magpie]`. In all why is loop variable's type unsigned and not corvid or enum corvid?

I think I have misunderstood enumeration constants.

Also from,

> As you might have guessed, positional values start from 0 onward, so in our example we have `raven` with value 0, `magpie` with 1, `jay` with 2, and `corvid_num` with 3. This last 3 is obviously the 3 we are interested in.

Is author right to say that raven should have value 0 and not magpie, if this is a typo, entirety of my confusion will dispense.

Comment: The author is wrong. Since values isn't explicit assigned, the first enum will be zero and the folliwing will be incremented by 1. So for the enums,  magpie is 0 , raven is 1, jay is 2, corvid_num is 3

Comment: It's a typo. You can check by printing the enum values, e.g. `printf("%d\n", magpie);` will print 0.

Comment: That is a bizare way to initialize an array..

Comment: @hetepeperfan it's an [extension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAdLwUXRUvg) to the C language (present in GCC IIRC).

Comment: @hetepeperfan why bizare? It is an easy way to map enum values to its name for printing them if needed. It is also safe in case you add new values in the middle of the enum list.

Comment: @alagner this is standard C since C99. You might mean an extension to C++

Comment: I see it are designator expressions, I've never seen them in the wild. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization. They seem very handy indeed.

Comment: @Gerhardh OK, I wasn't aware that feature made its way to the standard in C99, I'm sure it's been an extension in C90 though.

Comment: The designated array initializers were quite handy for a keyboard firmware implementation where they can be used like `key_remap[] = { [KEY_CAPS_LOCK] = KEY_CTRL }`;.

Answer (score 6):

In the declaration `char const * const bird [ corvid_num ]`  the item between `[ ]` is the size of the array. In the initializer list, `[ raven ] = " raven "`, the item between `[ ]` is a so-called *designated initializer*, used to initialize a particular item in the array.

> Question 1 : Does ' [ magpie ] = " magpie "' imply that 'magpie'TH position refers to value "magpie".

Yes.

> Question 2 : According to loop, how is bird [0] equal to "raven" , since this is explicit and not a positional value.

Because enums are named constants. If an enumeration constant (`raven` etc) isn't given a number explicitly, it is given one implicitly, starting at 0. `raven` in your example is the second item in the enum, so it gets value 1 and whenever you type `raven` in the source it will be equivalent to typing `1`.

> As you might have guessed, positional values start from 0 onward, so in our example we have raven with value 0, magpie with 1, jay with 2, and corvid_num with 3. This last 3 is obviously the 3 we are interested in.

This is an error in *Gustedt - Modern C*. Errata might exist? The output from the example code is:

```
Corvid 0 is the magpie
Corvid 1 is the raven
Corvid 2 is the jay
```

Notably, if we had *not* used designated initializers but just done this:

```
char const * const bird [ corvid_num ] = 
{
    "raven",
    "magpie",
    "jay",
};
```

Then the output would instead have become

```
Corvid 0 is the raven
Corvid 1 is the magpie
Corvid 2 is the jay
```

Answer (score 2):

Each `enum` case gets the value of the previous case plus one, unless explicitly overridden, and the first case gets the value zero. So here `magpie` is `0`, `raven` is `1`, etc. (The quoted part saying otherwise is wrong.) The final case `corvid_num` is the count of other cases in the array, since the `+ 1` of that case accounts for the zero case in the beginning.

The array initialisation is using C99 designated initializers, which allows assigning values to specific indices and in any order, i.e., `[raven] = "raven"` initialises the index `raven` (here `1`). It would be possible to just traditionally list each value in order, but doing it this way allows reordering the enum cases without having to sync the changes with the array.